# How to build xml element in memory and then save to file?

Tags: c#, xml

I want to make an xml file but add certain elements selectively. I would like to build those elements in memory and be able to choose whether to be written to the xml file or not. Is this possible? I'm using C# WinForms. I already looked at XmlDocument which will allow me to build an entire xml in memory but I don't want this since it's not good for large data and also takes too much memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a stream, named say `stream`, then you can create an XmlWriter by

```
XmlWriter.Create(stream);
```

Then, you can create your elements, (which are type `XmlElement`), and call the `WriteTo` method on each element you want to add, passing as an argument the XmlWriter created by `XmlWriter.Create`.

Comment: How will I create a single XmlElement? I think it is tied with XmlDocument?

Comment: Is it possible to create the xml using XmlWriter and append some elements but also create a stream and append to that some other elements and then write the stream to the XmlWriter without affecting XmlWriter's work?

Answer (score 2):

If large data volume is your main concern, `XmlWriter` may be ideal. The API is perhaps not as elegant as `XElement` etc, but it is the most direct and efficient mechanism, and is designed for firehosing a one-way stream of data.

It has a twin, `XmlReader`, but that is **much harder** to get right - due to the complexities of processing incoming xml and accounting for child trees appropriately.

Comment: Already checked XmlWriter, but how do I build the element and then write it to file?

Comment: @user579674 - @Ken has the answer to that. Personally I *wouldn't* (I'd use raw `XmlWriter` in this scenario), but his answer quite directly answers your question.

Comment: I have a question about XmlWriter. Do I have to use it with "using" keyword? Also, if I don't close the xml, it doesn't write anything to the file. How do I set it so it writes directly to the file than buffering?

Comment: @user579674 set AutoFlush = true, usually. Of course, unless you are writing an xml *fragment* (not an xml *document*), an incomplete xml file is not valid, as it will lack the closing tag